# How to check for valid time format?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsregularexpression

I am trying to check if a string variable conforms to either hh:mm AM or hh:mm PM twelve hour time format. Where hh represents hours, mm represents minutes and AM or PM represents morning or evening. I have a CSV file where each line contains a time in 12-hour format for instance 01:00 PM or 12:00 AM. I am extracting each line and checking if it conforms to the desired format.

Comment: we unable to understand your question, please add some additional info.

Comment: You can use date formatter and check if date from string is nil with given format

Comment: Regular expression is bad idea of this, as it won't provide validation, only that the values conform to a given pattern - I mean, `16:71 AM` would probably pass most regular expressions, but it's not a valid value - so, the question is, what is it you are hoping to achieve

Comment: Hope the extra information helps

Comment: Hi @infinite369 see my answer, To use  'checkTimeIsValid' function to get time is valid or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the string to a date formatter with the required format. If it returns a `Date` object, then the string contains valid date.

```
func getDate(from string: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
    return dateFormatter.date(from: string)
}

if let date = getDate(from: "2019-02-14 9:28 PM") {
    print(date)
}
```

---

Check [NSDateFormatter.com](https://www.nsdateformatter.com/) for reference.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik now that i think about it, it makes sense. But if you actually try it with `HH` it works, although it shouldn't.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik aaaaah, the date format should be used differently when you use it with `a`. How come the other date format is allowed then? Why does it return a `Date` object?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a DateFormatter, but if you're insisting on using RegEx, give this a try:

```
let dateString = "21:23 PM"
if let thisMatches = dateString.range(of: "^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm)$", options: .regularExpression) {
    Swift.print("this is a time")
} else {
    Swift.print("this is not the time")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code get specified time is valid or not.

**Case1:**

```
let myTime = checkTimeIsValid(from: "01:28 AM")
print("Time Is Valid:", myTime) //Time Is Valid: true
```

**Case2:**

```
let myTime = checkTimeIsValid(from: "21:28 AM")
print("Time Is Valid:", myTime) //Time Is Valid: false
```

**Function:**

```
func checkTimeIsValid(from string: String) -> Bool {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    if (dateFormatter.date(from: string) != nil) {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```